# Trying to access certain information from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I asked this question before but did not get any actual answers. I created a website for my wife's jewelry. She wants a product page for each style she makes (bracelets, necklaces, etc.).

I created the database with a category section that has all the different categories she makes.  The only problem I have is I cannot get the information to show up on the product page. I get errors such as

> Notice: Undefined variable: item_number in C:\xampp\htdocs\pinkys_pearls\bracelets.php on line 83.

Here is my code for the page:

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<?php 
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php");
    $con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
        exit();

        //Initializing variable
        $item_number = "item_number";
        $description = "description";
        $category = "category";
        $price = "price";
        $qty = "qty";

        $sql = "SELECT category FROM products WHERE category='Bracelets';";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            // get all the product details
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); { 
                echo $item_number = $row["item_number"];
                $price = $row["price"];
                $desc = $row["description"];
                $category = $row["category"];
            }
        } 
        else {
            echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bracelets</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x=UA-comparable" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Pinky's Pearls is a website where one of a kind jewelry designed by Nichole <q>Nicki</q> can be seen and purchased">
    <meta name="keywords" content="jewelry, beads, bracelets, rings, pendants, necklaces, pearls, crystal">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="samuel jaycox">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="pictures/pinky.png">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0c9491c5b9.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center"  id="wrapper">
    <div id="banner-wrapper">
    <!---Company Header-->
    <header> 
        <div id="header">
            <img class="bracelet_header" src="pictures/headers/bracelets.jpg" alt="Bracelets">
            <audio autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="background-music">
                <source src="music/Albinoni-adagio-in-g-minor-acoustic-guitar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                <source src="music/Albinoni-adagio-in-g-minor-acoustic-guitar.wav" type="audio/wav">    
            </audio>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!---end of Company Header-->
    <br>
    <?php include_once("templates/template_navigation.php"); ?>     
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!--Start Comment page Body Content-->
    <div id="body-content">
        <div class="bracelet_body">
            <table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15">
                <tr>
                    <td width="19%" valign="top">
                        <img src="pictures/inventory/<?php echo $pid; ?>.png" width="142" height="188" alt="<?php echo $item_number; ?>" /><br />
                        <a href="pictures/inventory/<?php echo $pid; ?>.png">View Full Size Image</a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="81%" valign="top">
                        <h3><?php echo $item_number; ?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo "$".$price; ?>
                            <br /><br />
                            <?php echo $desc; ?>
                            <br />
                        </p>
                        <form  id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
                            <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                            <input class="button" type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Shopping Cart" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of Comment body-->
    <?php include_once("templates/template_footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `SELECT category FROM products WHERE category='Bracelets'` ...does it make the least sense, to select a known category name, by it's category name?? try to `SELECT *` ...

Comment: Right, and the loop won't be getting anything inside what you're trying to loop over with/for. Selecting only one column won't work also. You need to choose all of the ones that you're wanting to loop over for.

Comment: Do you know why you're not getting an additional error after the undefined variable notice you're getting? I'll give you a hint: a semi-colon is a perfectly valid character in PHP; it just stops certain things from working though. Have a look at the manual on this http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: There's just too much work to be done here for a single answer. You have a lot of undefined variables and it's unknown as to how you're wanting to use the form for.

Comment: I changed the SELECT category to SELECT *. Which ; are you referring to? I moved a curly bracket so the variables were defined and the errors are gone but i still do not have the information from the database showing up on my page. How can I access the information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing a closing curly bracket at a critical point -

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();

// RIGHT HERE 

    //Initializing variable
    $item_number = "item_number";
    $description = "description";
    $category = "category";
```

With out it, none of your variables are initialized, your SQL query is never run, etc.

Once you've fixed that, try again and if there are still related issues edit the question, otherwise start a new question for a new issue.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that. didn't realize the curly bracket was down the end of the php.

Comment: the variables were initialized but still can't get the info for the product page. But at least I have one tthing cleared up. Thanks.